# Assign admin role for facebook page over FaceBookGraph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page

I have facebook page and I am admin of that page. Now I want to assign admin role to some one from my friend list using Graph API.

In docs i found how i can list admins of one pege ussing accounts parametar, but i can't found how i can add some one to be page admin.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am afraid you can t do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, Its not possible.

Just think about it. If its allowed, then wouldn't any fb app start taking over your pages?

Also, If you want to manage fb page, then you can easily do that via their API, it allows everything one can do if they were an actual admin of the page.

Example: Status Update, Wall Post, Photo Upload, Events Management (Create/Invite), Comment, Like, Insights, etc. What else you need?

Comment: While it's currently not possible, it certainly is not infeasible or even impractical.  Facebook has a vast array of permissions that are granted to apps.  One permission, the manage_pages permission, could feasibly be used to grant access to manage the list of admins for a given page.

Comment: @Syed But something like similar done by mailchimp.It automatically add a advertiser user on our page. How is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PSpH.png) possible?

Comment: "it allows everything one can do if they were an actual admin of the page" - not everything, for example invite users who liked a post to like your page.

Answer (score 0):

If you POST to the graph /{pageID}/admins?access_token={Page_access_token}&owner_email={some user emai}  then you get this response from the server: "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Your app does not have the permissions to modify admins",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100

So if they say that my app does not have the permission to modify admins it is logic that some apps may have the permission, tome tokens. The problem is that the required permission code is not public on the API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add an admin via Graph API using Koala library for Ruby like this;
@page_api.put_connections('your page id' , 'roles', {'admin_id' => 'user id from your friend list'})